# Replace a sheet at the same googlesheet URL using R

Tags: r, googlesheets4

I have a dataframe that I want to populate a googlesheet with using R. This is to update a datasheet used by other people in my working team. I want this sheet to be located at the same URL each time its written (not the same folder URL, but the same sheet URL).

The following produces an error:

```
drive_upload(file_name, name = file_name, path = as_id("theurlformygooglesheet"), overwrite = TRUE)


Error: Parent specified via `path` is invalid:
x Is neither a folder nor a shared drive.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I see that this would work if I use the folder approach, but then the code creates a new URL, which I don't want. Is there a way to do this? Note that the sheet has a new name to reflect the date on which the code was run to update it.

Thanks